Rails project .scss partial file isn't being loaded
I have a component file for a css card called "_teapot_card.scss" located in the usual "components" folder along with other css components (that are working) such as the navbar.
It has been included via @import in the relevant _index.scss file.
I have triple and quadruple checked the spellings, done a hard refresh and restarted the rails server, yet for some reason this file just won't load when I serve the page (I'm in development environment).
Everything displays on the page (pictures, texts, etc) however the style from that one scss file just doesn't exist, and I can't figure out why.
Relevant HTML.ERB and .SCSS files below.
HTML
<div class="all-teapots-container">
  <% @teapots.each do |teapot| %>
    <div class="teapot-card">
      <div class="card-picture">
        <%= cl_image_tag(teapot.images.first.key, width: 300, height: 300, crop: :fill) %>
      </div>
      <div class="card-info-container">
        <div class="dimension-box">
          <%= image_tag "dimensions.png" %>
          <p class="teapot-height-text">H: <%= teapot.height %> mm</p>
          <p class="teapot-width-text">W: <%= teapot.width %> mm</p>
          <p class="teapot-depth-text">D: <%= teapot.depth %> mm</p>
        </div>
        <div class="capacity-box"><%= image_tag "capacity.png" %>
          <p class="teapot-ccs-text"><%= teapot.ccs %> cc</p>
        </div>
        <p>Weight: <%= teapot.weight %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= pagy_nav(@pagy).html_safe %>
</div>

_index.scss
@import "carousel";
@import "confirmation_button";
@import "navbar";
@import "teapot_card";
@import "text";
@import "wallpaper";

_teapot_card.scss
.teapot-card {
  background-color: $dark-gray;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;

  .card-info-container {
    .dimension-box {

      img {
        max-width: 150px;
        height: auto;
      }
      p {
        color: green;
      }
    }

    .capacity-box {
      max-width: 150px;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
}


Have you checked that the actual compiled CSS delivered to the browser matches your expectations? You can do it via the sources tab in the web browser. Depending on what version of Rails and what pipeline is being used there are quite a few scenarios where the assets pipeline could get "stuck" and deliver stale assets even if you restart the server.

I'm also not sure what you mean by "located in the usual "components" folder". This not a Rails nor a SASS convention. @include  is also soft deprechiated in modern versions of SASS. Use @use if you're using Dart-Sass (if you're not than you should as the other complilers are EOL). https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/

I found a solution--  running the cli command
rails assets:clobber

and then restarting the server fixed the issue.  Unfortunately I still do not know the cause, but at least the file is working and the style is being applied now.

because you've run rails assets:precompile at some point and all your assets started loading from public/assets. clobber removes public/assets. precompiling is for production only.

Thank you for the explanation-- You're right, I think I did run assets:precompile at some point when I was troubleshooting something else in order to test something.
